# Side effects of activity no longer visible?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, activity-lifecycle, onpause

I wrote a simple app reading a page of text via text-to-speech. It works in principle but now I need to implement onPause(), onResume() etc. in a way that would make sense to the end user.

Specifically about onPause() I have 2 options:

1. Pause reading, with the intent to
   continue exactly from point left.
2. Continue normally, as if the
   activity is still visible.

The 2nd option looks more sensible because if it's not a visual activity, why let visual disturbances interrupt speech?

However, I am not sure whether there are other system-wide considerations ("side-effects") that I must be taking into account when implementing onPause() as a "do nothing" function.

Aside from onPause() being called when an activity is no longer visible, are there other events or side-effect that I should take into consideration when deciding whether to stop or not to stop text-to-speech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that comes to mind is if the system runs out of memory. Activities that are out of sight can be killed by the system if it needs the memory. What I'd suggest doing is using a long running service rather than an Activity. Let the activity manage the service but let the service handle the reading of text. If you still want to use an Activity, I believe there is a setting you can set to make killing your unseen Activity a last resort.

Comment: @Spidy If the system runs out of memory then onDestroy() is called, at which point I will definitely stop speech. My only debate is about onPause() and perhaps onStop().

Comment: @an00b You might want to look at the activity lifecycle diagram. The onDestroy() will not be called. The activity will die and the reader will stop, but onDestroy() won't be called

Comment: @Spidy Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I am looking at the activity lifecycle diagram now and I see that onStop(), on the other hand, will definitely be called. Right? So the question remains about onPause().

Comment: @an00b Nothing will be called. The Activity is killed and your code doesn't get activated. So onPause() is when you save an pertinent data that you'll need if the Activity is killed and restarted later to resume its operations

Comment: @Spidy What??? Looking at the [diagram](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png), there is no way the red box "Process is killed" is reached without going through onStop() first. Either the documentation is flawed or... please explain.

Comment: @an00b Sorry, you're right. The application will definitely hit onStop() before it hides the Activity. I was thinking that the Activity would be killed at onPause() but in that case the Activity would still be displayed.

Comment: @Spidy OK thanks for the clarification. I am very new to this so I can be confused very easily. The documentation says "followed by either onResume() if the activity returns back to the front,  or onStop() if it becomes invisible to the user", although in the diagram there is a strange line between onPause() and "Other applications need memory"... For n00bs like me, this is VERY confusing.

Comment: @an00b This means that if another Activity is overlaying the current Activity but not completely blocking it (ie: A pop up box) and the system runs out of memory for whatever reason, the Activity that is partially hidden and only gone through onPause() will be killed without moving to onStop()

Comment: @Spidy Wow! So it **is** possible to be killed without going through onStop(). The documentation, then, is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

If you were being interrupted by the phone (or anything people listen to), you wouldn't want to keep producing sound.

Comment: Excellent point. Is it possible to check in onPause() for the **type** of the event that's interrupted my activity and, based on that, decide whether to stop or continue?

Comment: You could check the phone's state in onPause() to see if it was call, but in a more general sense, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way of doing that.